# Why is the decay $\omega \rightarrow \eta \pi^0$ forbidden?

Tags: particle-physics, mesons

I understand that it is due to C conservation, but I'd like some more information - perhaps it's simpler than I'm imagining.

Similarly for the decay  $\omega \rightarrow \rho \gamma$.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the answer lies in $G$-parity, although Non-conservation of a property doesn't mean violation under all circumstances.

Comment: look at isospin conservation http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/parint.html, it  does not have decaying quark, but the isospin balance left and right is wrong, pions have isospin one (for the title decay).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me what is troubling you.

You must have ascertained by now from your [PDG listings](http://pdg.lbl.gov/index.html) that $J^{PC}$ for the particles involved is
$$
\omega, \rho^0, \gamma : \qquad 1^{--} \\
\eta, \pi^0 :\qquad 0^{-+} ~~.
$$
Both strong and EM interactions preserve *C*, here clearly mismatched (multiplicatively) in the two decays you are proposing.

What qualms would you have?